# log4j2 level expansion in field

Tags: java, log4j2

What is the correct way to put the level of the log message into a field in log4j2? Example below.

In log4j2 I have an `SMTPAppender` configured as so:

```
<SMTP name="Email" smtpHost="..." smtpPort="..."
      smtpUsername="..." smtpPassword="..." ignoreExceptions="false"
      to="..."
      from="..."
      subject="[$${env:INSTANCE_ID}] [$${level}] log message">
</SMTP>
```

Everything is working fine except the level. Ideally I'd like it to output something like `[PROD] [WARN] log message`, but my guess at `$${level}` was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using two different appenders with two different names and separate subject lines?

```
<Appenders>
    <SMTP name="MailWarn" subject="Warn Log" to="..." from="..."
          smtpHost="..." smtpPort="..." bufferSize="...">
    </SMTP>
    <SMTP name="MailError" subject="Error Log" to="..." from="..."
          smtpHost="..." smtpPort="..." bufferSize="...">
    </SMTP>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Thanks, clever way of solving my immediate problem.